# How to capture milliseconds in grails domain

Tags: mysql, grails, time

I have a grails domain that stores data in MySQL.

In it I have a `Date` property which creates a `DateTime` field in the DB. However, I also wish to capture the milliseconds in addition to the date.

Is there a way to capture milliseconds?

Example:

```
Class MyClass {

  Date dateCreated

}
```

stores data in MySQL as `2014-10-06 16:21:57` but I'd like to capture milliseconds as well.

Comment: I wanted to capture the milliseconds in MySQL for times when I need to run queries to determine the exact time when request was created..

Comment: mysql supports this, e.g. you can create a column of type datetime(3) if you create a table by hand.  I too am looking for a way to get grails to do this for me

Answer (score 2):

MySQL 5.6.4 and up can save milliseconds in the database for datetime objects by defining the amount of fractional points for the object. (Read more here: [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)). By default Grails/Gorm doesn't do this. Fortunately, this is easily solved by defining a sqlType in the domain like this:

```
class ExampleDomain {
    Date date

    static mapping = {
        date sqlType: 'datetime(3)'
    }
}
```

Comment: sqlType: 'datetime(3)' is not valid:  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(3)..."

Comment: @Mexx which MySql version are you running?

Comment: MySQL Version is 5.5.42. Oh now I see it is to old. I'm using bigint(20) now. To save the nanoseconds till unix epoch.

Answer (score 0):

You could use bigint(20). Your groovy/grails domain could look like that if you want to store the nanoseconds since unix epoch automatically when a instance will be saved:

```
class myClass {

  Integer id
  Long timestamp = System.nanoTime()

  static mapping = {
    timestamp sqlType: "bigint"
  }
}
```